# Erro na consulta do cadastro no bd

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Eu fiz uma página de cadastro no meu site, que pra fazer o cadastro precisa de cpf e email. Fiz um SELECT para ver se já existe, se sim, nao inserir, do contrario nao insere. Deixei o cpf como pk e email como unique. Quando coloco um cpf existente ele mostra o alert que eu fiz dizendo que já existe, mas quando é um cpf novo e email que já ta no bd, ele nao informa e faz o cadastro.

```
    $var1 = $_POST['cpf'];
    $var2 = $_POST['email'];

  $query = "SELECT * FROM teste WHERE email = '$var2'";
  $query = "SELECT * FROM teste WHERE cpf = '$var1'";


      $querySelect = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($querySelect) > 0) {
          echo"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Cadastro existente.');window.location.href='cadastro.php';</script>";
        }

            $var1 = $_POST['cpf'];
            $var2 = $_POST['email'];


            $sql = 'INSERT INTO teste (cpf, email) VALUES (?,?)';

            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

            $var1 = $_POST['cpf'];
            $var2 = $_POST['email'];


            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $var1, $var2);
            $stmt->execute();

            echo"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Cadastro realizado com sucesso.');window.location.href='index.php';</script>";

            if(!$stmt){
              echo 'erro na consulta: '. $conn->error .' - '. $conn->error;
            }
```

E no `SELECT` que eu fiz, eu tentei colocar AND, mas ficou pior ainda, nem checava se o cpf estava lá, sempre concluía o cadastro. Conseguem ver algum erro?

Comment: pq não faz uma consulta só com um `OR` verificando `email` e `cpf` se tiver algum registro é pq algum dos dois já existe. Tem muito código repetido aí O.o

Comment: Realmente kkkkk meu código fica uma bagunça no inicio, mas depois eu ajeito tudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você faz isso:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM teste WHERE email = '$var2'";
$query = "SELECT * FROM teste WHERE cpf = '$var1'";
```

Você diz que a variável está recebendo um valor, no caso usando a mesma variável, você estará perdendo o primeiro select que nunca será executado, então crie duas variaveis, duas consultas, adicione mais condicionais, ou simplesmente faça com um OR na consulta:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM teste WHERE email = '".$var2."' OR cpf = '".$var1."'";
```

Código completo:

```
$var1 = $_POST['cpf'];
$var2 = $_POST['email'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM teste WHERE email = '".$var2."' OR cpf = '".$var1."'";
$querySelect = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($querySelect) > 0) {
    echo"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Cadastro existente.');window.location.href='cadastro.php';</script>";
}
$sql = 'INSERT INTO teste (cpf, email) VALUES (?,?)';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $var1, $var2);
$stmt->execute();

echo"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Cadastro realizado com sucesso.');window.location.href='index.php';</script>";

if(!$stmt){
    echo 'erro na consulta: '. $conn->error .' - '. $conn->error;
}
```

> Nota: Como rray disse, tem muito código duplicado aí, da uma estudada
>   em lógica de programação, acho que pode ajudar bastante

Answer (score 2):

Você está realizando apenas uma leitura, no caso, você está substituindo:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM teste WHERE email = '$var2'";
```

por

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM teste WHERE cpf = '$var1'";
```

Faça da seguinte forma:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM teste WHERE email = '$var2' OR cpf='$var1';
```